# Deploy IBM Mobile v8.0.0 MobileFirst HTTP Adater error - "Adapter deployment failed: A database error was detected."

Tags: compiler-errors, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am getting  "Adapter deployment failed: A database error was detected." ERROR while deploying the HTTP adapter

Iam  just trying to deploy this auto generated adapter code  with auto generated project, but it gives above error message.

IBM worklight version 8.0.0 plugin
Eclipse Mars 2
Win7

[image: Auto generated Adapter code]

[image: This is how i created Adapter]

Comment: Your question is not clear. There are no "projects" in v8.0 - what are you referring to here? also, the eclipse plug-in for v8.0 does not generates any adapters... provide exact step-by-step reproduction instructions.

Comment: Updated my question, please check if you require any other information

Comment: What you're using in your Eclipse is absolutely not v8.0. Again, **there is no adapters creation support in Eclipse in v8.0**. 1) Please check which version you're actually using. 2) Where are you trying to deploy it to?

Comment: What is the exact build version of your MFP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're using, it's not MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, as the Studio plug-in for Eclipse in v8.0 does not have a UI to generate adapters.

You're using 7.1 and you may have also installed 8.0, but they do different things entirely.

As for the database error - you should have provided the server log as well as the full actual log; that single error line is unclear.

What you can do is delete your workspace in Eclipse in order to generate a new 7.1 server instance, and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.